# What is the point of calling initComponents() through class constructor in netbeans, though it can be called through main methods too?

Tags: java, methods, netbeans, constructor

[image: calling initComponents through constructor]

Difference between calling initComponents() through UserMode Constructor and calling initComponents() through the main method.

Comment: since it is a private method you cannot call it through main methods unless you are talking about only the main method in the same class.

Comment: yes, I'm talking about the main method in the same class.

Comment: By calling the method in the constructor you make sure that 1) The init method gets called for every created object of said class and 2) it only gets called once. Sure you could just add a comment telling the people who use that class that they have to manually call this method, but why introduce potential errors and problems when you can just hide the method and design the class in a way that the user only has to call the constructor and not worry about anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As comment says, being a `private` method forbis its call from external, including the class containing the `main(...)` method of the Java program.

Furthermore, the `main(...)` method in Java programs are static, resulting that they can call only other static methods (or the methods of the global, or locally created objects). Doing something like a

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...
  UserMode um = new UserMode();
  um.initComponents();
  ...
}
```

would work if `initComponents()` would not be private, but it would be still a bad practice: the constructor of `UserMode` should actually initialize the class; doing it in two steps needs some stronger reason.